# Firebase Rules for a social app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to extend a [social android aap](https://github.com/rozdoum/social-app-android), currently its rules are public, its data structure is something like this,

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "postId1" : {
      "authorId" : "abcd",
    },
    "postId2" : {
      "authorId" : "abcd",

    },
    "postId3" : {
      "authorId2" : "wxyz",

    },
    "postId4" : {
      "authorId2" : "wxyz",
    }
  }
}
```

I want to allow an authenticated user to create and delete his own post  in "posts" node
I tried this,

```
{
  "rules": {
        ".read":"auth.uid != null",
        ".write":false,
      "questions": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
}}
```

But this does not allow a user to create a post although a user can edit or delete his pre-existing post in "posts" node, it seems that there is no write permission within the "posts" node.
But if i allow write permission for "posts" then due to cascading rules, every authenticated user can access other's data. How can I achieve my desired functionality?

Answer (score 2):

First please see firebase-bolt for writing rules for real time database: https://github.com/firebase/bolt

This tool makes it easy to write rules.

And for your rules here is a sample which will allow only the author to update post:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    "posts": {
      "$postId": {
        ".write": "data.val() == null && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid || data.val() != null && newData.val() != null && data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid || data.val() != null && newData.val() == null && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
      },
      ".read": "auth.uid != null"
    }
  }
}
```

and the firebase bolt equivalent is below :

```
path / {
    read() {auth.uid != null}
}

path /posts {
    read() {auth.uid != null}
    /{postId}{
    create() { this.uid == auth.uid}
    delete() { this.uid == auth.uid}
    update() { prior(this.uid) == auth.uid}
    }
}
```

Comment: bro i think its still there, i want rules for "posts" node, these rules are not allowing to create a content in "posts".

Comment: @ShahzadAkram As far as I can see this grants create and update permissions to the `path /posts/$postId`. If it's failing for you with these rules, show the code that performs the write to the database.

Comment: `databaseReference.updateChildren("/posts/" + post.getId(), postValues)`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , Bro I am new to firebase but according to my understandings, I need to write `path /posts/` only, $postId is not a path where i want to write, it is a post identity after its creation, if I am wrong kindly guide me .

Comment: $postId mean a variable value. it means that after post/ there will be auto generated or user generated unique ids under which a post will be present.

Comment: $postId can be postId1, postId2 etc.

Comment: Your write should work with the rules from Umar. Did you try it? What was the exact error message?

Comment: After some research I have found this code to work according to my expectations `".write":"data.child('uid').val()== auth.uid || newData.val() !== null"` , if there is any vulnerability kindly guide me..

Comment: it will get bypassed because you have OR instead of AND so even if the condition of auth fails, when new data is not null rules allows it to be written successfully.

Comment: what you are trying to do is already present in my answer, have you tried them ?